# CSS Bootstrap: inline form with error message

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I`m using Bootstrap v3.2. I have a inline-form but I want to show a error message, but its not nice:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/BCM6bZH.png]

Is there a way to do this:
[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <p class="lead">{{errorMsg}}</p>
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" name="loginForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" type="text" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam" required>
            <div>
                <span style="float:left" class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Wachtwoord" required>
    </div>
        <button onclick="javascript:void(0)"class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" ng-click="login()">Log in</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The problem is that the input goes up and I don`t want that.

Comment: Please indent your html so we don't have to guess what belongs inside what.

Comment: You're not using any of the markup for validation states..? (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation)

Comment: But thats not working with a inline form

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use this snippet

**HTML:**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <p class="lead">{{errorMsg}}</p>
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" name="loginForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" type="text" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam" required>
            <div>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign error-sign"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Wachtwoord" required>
    </div>
        <button onclick="javascript:void(0)"class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" ng-click="login()">Log in</button>
    </form>
</div><div class="jumbotron">
    <p class="lead">{{errorMsg}}</p>
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" name="loginForm">
        <div class="form-group has-warning has-feedback">
          <label class="control-label sr-only" for="username">Gebruikersnaam</label>
          <input class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" id="username" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam" required="" type="text">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Wachtwoord" required="" type="password">
        </div>
        <button onclick="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" ng-click="login()">Log in</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.form-inline .form-group {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.error-sign {
    float:left;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
```

You can see that [here](http://www.bootply.com/11POqRj19M)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me..

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <p class="lead">{{errorMsg}}</p>
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" name="loginForm">
        <div class="form-group has-warning has-feedback">
          <label class="control-label sr-only" for="username">Gebruikersnaam</label>
          <input class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam" required>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Wachtwoord" required>
        </div>
        <button onclick="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" ng-click="login()">Log in</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I've also made a bootply: http://www.bootply.com/BtRzVTdeTU

Comment: No, I want the warning sign under the input (see screenshot)